# What is the difference between Mongoose toObject and toJSON?

Tags: mongoose

The [Mongoose documentation for toObject](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) lists features, options, and gives examples of functionality of `toObject`.

The Mongoose documentation for `toJSON` says the options are the same as toObject, but doesn't explain what `toJSON` does.  [Elsewhere the documentation says](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON)

> toJSON is exactly the same as the toObject option but only applies
>   when the document's toJSON method is called.

Is `toJSON` an alias of `toObject`?  If not, what are the differences?

Answer (score 28):

A look at the [source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/document.js) reveals that both methods call an internal `$toObject` method, but with `toJSON` passing a second, `true` parameter:

```js
Document.prototype.toObject = function (options) {
  return this.$toObject(options);
};
...
Document.prototype.toJSON = function (options) {
  return this.$toObject(options, true);
};
```

That second parameter determines whether `$toObject` uses the `toJSON` or `toObject` schema options for its defaults. So unless those schema options are configured differently, the two methods are identical.

Comment: As a side note it actually makes sense to use a different configuration of toJSON - you can do some transformations before returning an object from controller (in express res.json(object) calls JSON.stringify that is object.toJSON) - for instance depopulate some entries to avoid stack overflow...

Answer (score 7):

Like [JohnnyHK's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31762974/1766225) said, there is no difference between `toJSON` and `toObject`. My guess is that, `toJSON` was created to support the `JSON.stringify` method.

From the [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), if an object has the `toJSON` property as a function, `JSON.stringify` will use the `toJSON` function to serialize the object instead of the object itself.

Answer (score 5):

For my use case, this is what I got:

- `.toJSON`'s advantage is that it's used automatically by `JSON.stringify`. If you set the schema option `toJSON` to your re-shaping options, then an object with the proper shape will be built when you stringify a document with that schema
- `.toObject`'s advantage is that some times `JSON.stringify` runs after breaking the link between the document and the schema, so that no re-shaping can happen. In such a case, you just call the document method `toObject` with those options to get an object with the proper shape.

Example

- Having:

```js
const reshapingOptions = {

    // include .id (it's a virtual)
    virtuals: true,

    // exclude .__v
    versionKey: false,

    // exclude ._id
    transform: function (doc, ret) {
        delete ret._id;
        return ret;
    },

};

const friendSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    givenName: String,
    familyName: String,
}, { toJSON: reshapingOptions });

const friendModel = mongoose.model('Friend', friendSchema);

const john = friendModel.findOne({ givenName: 'John' });
if (!john) {
    res.status(404).json({ error: 'No John Found' });
}
```

- the statement

  ```js
  JSON.stringify(john);
  ```

  returned:

```js
{
    "id": "...",
    "givenName": "John",
    "familyName": "Doe"
}
```

- but this equally innocent statement

  ```js
  JSON.stringify({ 
      ...john, // the spread breaks the link
      role: 'dummy friend' 
  })
  ```

  suddenly returned:

```js
{
    "_id": "...",
    "givenName": "John",
    "familyName": "Doe",
    "__v": 0,
    "role": "dummy friend"
}
```

- So that I used

  ```js
  res.json({ 
      ...john.toObject(reshapingOptions), 
      role: 'dummy friend' 
  })
  ```

  to get:

```js
{
    "id": "...",
    "givenName": "John",
    "familyName": "Doe",
    "role": "dummy friend"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While developing a plugin for the `toObject` and `toJSON` methods, I discovered that `toObject` is also called during save operations.  This can be detrimental.  For example, if a plugin that sets `toObject` (like mine) alters fields, the result of that alteration will be persisted.

Comment: This might be an issue to bring up on Github:  https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues

Comment: @steampowered Fred I am using .toObject() and on the object whose value I am assiging from docs.toObject(), I am changing the values, but when I am calling docs.save then the value changed by new object is not there in MongoDB. Which i want to happen so everything is working perfectly for me, Can you please tell me how was it detrimental for your case? I don't get you?