# Loop through Mongoose objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loops, mongoose

I have a Mongoose result object that I'd like to loop through, but it seems to behave differently than a classic object.

Usually, you can't loop through nonenumerable properties with [`for…in loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), but that seems to work here. Hence, that doesn't work with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) though it's supposed to loop through the same properties as `for…in`…

Furthermore, [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) which is supposed to loop through every properties (enumerable or not) doesn't return any of the fetched values. I don't really get what's happening here.

Here is some sample code and its output to illustrate this:

```
MediaModel.findById('558d0b3a5fa02e7e218b470c', function (err, media) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }

    console.log(media);
    console.log("\n --- \n");
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(media));
    console.log("\n---\n");

    for (var prop in media) {
        console.log(prop + ' -- Enumerable : ' +   media.propertyIsEnumerable(prop) + ' -- hasOwnProperty : ' + media.hasOwnProperty(prop) + "\n");
    }
});
```

This it the output in the console:

```
{ _id: 558d0b3a5fa02e7e218b470c,
  name: '54ae5d587860b4.61272171',
  cover: true,
  size: 144,
  audio: 
   { es: '54ae5ec1e31c68.83020900',
     en: '54ae5ec240dd98.65329366',
     fr: '54ae5ec2950737.15028179',
     pt: '54ae5ec2e3bcf5.08479198',
     ar: '54ae5ec33ab8f5.67860635',
     ru: '54ae5ec393d300.66214842' },
  comments: [] }

 --- 

[ '$__',
  'isNew',
  'errors',
  '_doc',
  '$__original_save',
  'save',
  '_pres',
  '_posts' ]

---

$__ -- Enumerable : true -- hasOwnProperty : true

isNew -- Enumerable : true -- hasOwnProperty : true

errors -- Enumerable : true -- hasOwnProperty : true

_doc -- Enumerable : true -- hasOwnProperty : true

$__original_save -- Enumerable : true -- hasOwnProperty : true

save -- Enumerable : true -- hasOwnProperty : true

_pres -- Enumerable : true -- hasOwnProperty : true

_posts -- Enumerable : true -- hasOwnProperty : true

db -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

discriminators -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

__v -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

id -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

_id -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

comments -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

size -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

length -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

cover -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

imdbId -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

imdbRating -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

year -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

actors -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

writers -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

director -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

genre -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

name -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

schema -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

collection -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__handleSave -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__delta -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__version -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

increment -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__where -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

remove -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

model -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

on -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

once -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

emit -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

listeners -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

removeListener -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

setMaxListeners -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

removeAllListeners -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

addListener -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__buildDoc -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

init -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__storeShard -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

hook -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

pre -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

post -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

removePre -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

_lazySetupHooks -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

update -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

set -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__shouldModify -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__set -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

getValue -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

setValue -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

get -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__path -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

markModified -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

modifiedPaths -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

isModified -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

isDirectModified -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

isInit -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

isSelected -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

validate -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

validateSync -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

invalidate -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$markValid -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$isValid -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__reset -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__dirty -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__setSchema -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__getArrayPathsToValidate -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__getAllSubdocs -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__registerHooksFromSchema -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__handleReject -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$toObject -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

toObject -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

toJSON -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

inspect -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

toString -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

equals -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

populate -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

execPopulate -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

populated -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false

$__fullPath -- Enumerable : false -- hasOwnProperty : false
```

In the end, I'd like to loop through `media.audio` but I can't figure out how.

It works by doing `var audio = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(media.audio)));` and then loop through it with a `for…in`, but I don't find this to be the proper way of doing it!

Comment: DId you try loop through `media.audio.toObject()` object?

Comment: That works perfectly! There's actually a [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503450/how-do-you-turn-a-mongoose-document-into-a-plain-object) that explains just that.

Comment: Nevertheless, how is that I get nonenumerable properties with `for…in`, as `media` is still a JS object?

Comment: Does this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024149/is-it-possible-to-get-the-non-enumerable-inherited-property-names-of-an-object#answer-8024294 ?

Comment: There's also a quite good synthesis on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, question is not fresh, but this situation may still become a piece of pain. You may use `toJSON` or `toObject` method to get normal, iterable object. Just like this:

```
media = media.toJSON()
Object.keys(media.audio).forEach(...)
```

---

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756673/what-is-the-difference-between-mongoose-toobject-and-tojson) for details about `toJSON` an `toObject`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with:

```
var media = {
    _id: '558d0b3a5fa02e7e218b470c',
    name: '54ae5d587860b4.61272171',
    cover: true,
    size: 144,
    audio: {
        es: '54ae5ec1e31c68.83020900',
        en: '54ae5ec240dd98.65329366',
        fr: '54ae5ec2950737.15028179',
        pt: '54ae5ec2e3bcf5.08479198',
        ar: '54ae5ec33ab8f5.67860635',
        ru: '54ae5ec393d300.66214842'
    },
    comments: []
};

for (var property in media.audio) {
    if (media.audio.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        console.log(property);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's the output:
`$__
isNew
errors
_doc
$__original_save
save
_pres
_posts
name
toObject
toJSON
$__isNested
lang
__v
id
_id
audio
comments
size
length
cover`

Comment: I had tried `for…in` with either `media` and `media.audio` that doesn't change the output… And I still can't loop through the `media.audio` object.